# Is there a proper term for these?

Tags: soft-question, notation

The 'square root' sign is formally the 'radical symbol'.

'Brackets' are formally 'parentheses'

Is there a formal term for the 'fraction sign' or say the 'absolute value bars'?

EDIT: I can see some downvotes. It would be helpful if I could receive some feedback as to why this question is not wanted as to not ask similar questions in the future. A vote has been cast as 'Unclear' but I would think that my question is a relatively simple question. I'm not quite sure how it is 'unclear'.

Comment: It's unclear what you regard as "proper term" or "formally". The fraction bar $\frac{\ }{}$ just doesn't have a real name because people tend to not talk about the _shape_ but about the meaning ("the fraction $\frac xy$"). If the shape is to be referenced, a horizontal line should be fair enough. Also AFAIK, brackets denote $[]$ and parentheses denote $()$.

Comment: I would have accepted that as an answer, the fact that it doesn't have a real name. I was wondering if there was one that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: By what sources do you have the distinction square root symbol vs. radical symbol and brackets vs. parentheses? This may be a question about typography rather than math ...

Comment: @Trogdor I don't have any reference saying that there _is no name for $x$_ and that's probably impossible to find. Do you want me to post that as an answer anyway?

Comment: @AlexR Not actually true what you say about brackets: it means different things in different dialects: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Names_for_various_bracket_symbols

Comment: @Chappers I guessed so, that's why I wrote _as far as I know_ ;) Thanks for the link, though.

Comment: @AlexR:  It depends on what is meant by "the fraction sign".  While the horizontal bar is indeed simply called "the horizontal bar" or similar, the sloping line or slash for fractions has the Latin-derived name "solidus" (after a Roman coin).  The Wikipedia article on Fraction has this [Vocabulary section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Vocabulary) and a wider discussion [Earliest Uses of Symbols for Fractions](http://jeff560.tripod.com/fractions.html) was collected by Jeff Miller.

Comment: Many operations induce tacit parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

I think the line in a fraction is called a vinculum.

Answer (score 1):

*Brackets* really refers to a whole class of paired symbols, $()$ and $[]$ being only the most common. And as I said in the comments, the word by itself actually means different sorts in different dialects. (See [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Names_for_various_bracket_symbols).)

While the symbol $/$ is variously called the [slash, forward slash, solidus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_(punctuation)#Alternative_names), and so on, the symbol in a vertically typeset fraction seems to just be called the fraction bar (and no doubt used to be typeset using dashes and lines of various lengths: printers have always hated mathematicians and their weird symbols and propensity for requiring fairly complicated typesetting). The symbol $\div$ is called the [obelus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obelus).

In general, Wikipedia has a large proportion of all the information you want to know about typographical symbols. (My favourite is the one about [how to use the various dashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), or the [Manual of Style article on the same](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Dashes), which is far more complicated than you'd expect. And you've almost certainly used the n-dash wrongly in the past.)